# JSON Model Suggestion

Tags: json, model-view-controller, alamofire, swift4, xcode9

I gotta to create a good model to pass the data received from JSON to my other controllers. How would you guys do that? I need to access these properties inside of my struct wherever I want in the project, to be able to populate UI components and etc.

This is my API Response file:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct Description: Decodable {
    let data: [data]
}

struct data: Decodable {

    let id:Int?
    let descricao:String?
    let urlImagem:String?
}

func callApi(completion: @escaping (String, String) -> Void) {

    guard let _url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria")else{return}
    Alamofire.request(_url).responseJSON { (response) in

        guard let info = response.data else{return}

        do{
            let dataParsed = try JSONDecoder().decode(Description.self, from: info)

            for aData in dataParsed.data {


                completion(aData.descricao!, aData.urlImagem!)
            }

        }catch{
        print("Error serialization: \(error)")


}
}
}
```

This is the JSON model I'm receiving:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "descricao": "Games",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/39ahd9aq5l9101brf3b8dq58.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/3D-Gaming.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "descricao": "Livros",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-6Bta1H9d22g\/UJAIJbqcHhI\/AAAAAAAAKi4\/hvgjWrlFc64\/s1600\/resenha-missiologia.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "descricao": "Celulares",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/pt.seaicons.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/11\/Mobile-Smartphone-icon.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "descricao": "Inform\u00e1tica",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/portal.ifrn.edu.br\/campus\/ceara-mirim\/noticias\/ifrn-oferece-curso-de-informatica-basica-para-pais-dos-estudantes\/image_preview"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "descricao": "Eletrodom\u00e9stico",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/classificados.folharegiao.com.br\/files\/classificados_categoria\/photo\/8\/sm_4d5ed3beb0f31b61cb9a01e46ecd0cf9.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "descricao": "TVs",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/i.utdstc.com\/icons\/256\/terrarium-tv-android.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "descricao": "Filmes e S\u00e9ries",
      "urlImagem": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/801033586438733824\/91Y_N91t_reasonably_small.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "descricao": "M\u00f3veis e Decora\u00e7\u00f5es",
      "urlImagem": "https:\/\/image.flaticon.com\/icons\/png\/128\/148\/148188.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "descricao": "Moda, Beleza e Perfumaria",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/icon-icons.com\/icons2\/196\/PNG\/128\/fashion_23852.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "descricao": "Papelaria",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/esen.pt\/in\/images\/stories\/skills_256.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please include the API response as text in your question.

Comment: I just updated to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Model Refactor

Firstly, lets address the model name for `data`.
Make it `ImageData` because type names should be Pascal Cased (it's just a good coding convention). e.g. `ClassName`, `StructName`, `PascalCase`.
We also don't want it to be called `Data` because that will overload `Foundation`'s `Data` type.

So our models will be:

```
struct Description: Decodable {
    let data: [ImageData]
}

struct ImageData: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let descricao: String
    let urlImagem: String
}
```

---

### 2. Singleton

> I need to access these properties inside of my struct wherever I want
>   in the project

In that case, I would use a singleton that has a reference to the image array.

Example:

```
class SharedManager {        
    static let shared = SharedManager()
    private init() {}

    var images: [ImageData]?
}
```

---

### 3. Service Helper

Lets write a new class called `APIHelper` which will act like a service helper. Here, we will have the `Alamofire` logic so lets improve on that too.

1. Lets rename `callApi(completion:)` to something more meaningful, say, `getImages(completion:)`
2. Lets make this a class method for convenience.
3. Also instead of the completion closure providing `(String, String)`, let it provide `[ImageData]?`; i.e. the array of `ImageData` models.

   - For easy access later in the app
   - This array is optional in case the url is invalid or the request/parsing fails (just keeping it simple)

:

```
class APIHelper {

    class func getImages(completion: @escaping ([ImageData]?)->Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria")
            else {
                completion(nil)
                return
        }

        Alamofire
            .request(url)
            .responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    do {
                        let myImages = try JSONDecoder().decode(Description.self,
                                                                from: response.data!)
                        completion(myImages.data)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil)
                }
        }
    }

}
```

---

### 4. Set the array in the singleton

Call `getImages(completion:)` once to set `SharedManager.shared.images` like so:

```
APIHelper.getImages { (imageData) in
    print(imageData)
    SharedManager.shared.images = imageData
}
```

---

### 5. Usage

Now you should be able to access the image array via `SharedManager.shared.images` at anytime and anywhere (within you app scope ofcourse)

Just your basic array handling logic but here are a few examples:

- Loop through them:

  ```
  for imageData in SharedManager.shared.images ?? [] {
      print(imageData)
  }
  ```
- Access image at a particular index

  ```
  let imageIndex = 1
  let imageURL = SharedManager.shared.images?[imageIndex].urlImagem
  print(imageURL)
  ```
- Find an image with a particular id:

  ```
  let imageIDToFind = 7
  let foundImage = SharedManager.shared.images?.first { $0.id == imageIDToFind }
  print(foundImage)
  ```

Comment: Man, I have no words to thank you for all information you gave me and also for being patient. I only have one question. Le'ts say I want to get all Descriptions, how can I do that? Because if I say let firstImageURL = SharedManager.shared.images?.first?.description, I'll get only the first. How can I access each position? Same for url images and id.

Comment: @BrunoVavretchek Updated answer. It's basically just your normal array handling techniques. Glad to help though :)